# How to multiply String in java

Tags: java, string

i would like to multiply string by an interger value, for what im working on is a health system for a simple game. 
so what i did was made an ASCII heart and would like to take this away and add to this depending on what the players health is like.

```
    String heart = "  _  _ ";
    String heart2 =" ( \/ )";
    String heart3 ="  \  / ";
    String heart4 = "  \/  ";
```

so to output the player health would be like:

```
    System.out.println(heart*8);
    System.out.println(heart2*8);
    System.out.println(heart3*8);
    System.out.println(heart4*8);
```

to equal an output like this

```
      _  _   _  _   _  _   _  _   _  _   _  _   _  _   _  _
     ( \/ ) ( \/ ) ( \/ ) ( \/ ) ( \/ ) ( \/ ) ( \/ ) ( \/ )
      \  /   \  /   \  /   \  /   \  /   \  /   \  /   \  / 
       \/     \/     \/     \/     \/     \/     \/     \/
```

and to take away a health id simply just multiply if by one less number,

```
    System.out.println(heart*7);
    System.out.println(heart2*7);
    System.out.println(heart3*7);
    System.out.println(heart4*7);
```

to have an output of

```
      _  _   _  _   _  _   _  _   _  _   _  _   _  _  
     ( \/ ) ( \/ ) ( \/ ) ( \/ ) ( \/ ) ( \/ ) ( \/ ) 
      \  /   \  /   \  /   \  /   \  /   \  /   \  /   
       \/     \/     \/     \/     \/     \/     \/
```

but from what i'm doing nothing seems to be happening as you cannot multiply string this way, could someone please help me multiply this out. Thanks

Comment: `String` doesn't support multiplication-operations in java and most other languages since it's hard to define a consistent and logical multiplication-operation for string (for e.g. should `"abc" * 2` mean "abcabc" or "aabbcc" or just multiply each element in the vector of characters by 2?). This task can be solved easily using for-loops, so theres no need at all for a multiplication-operation anyways.

Comment: Check the link @Kenney sent and also use string array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try printing line by line instead of the whole pattern at once

```
class PrintHeartzzz{

    public static void main(String[] args){
      StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
      int n=8;

      prepareLine("  _  _ ",sb,n);
      prepareLine(" ( \\/ )",sb,n);
      prepareLine("  \\  / ",sb,n);
      prepareLine("   \\/  ",sb,n);

      System.out.println(sb);

    }

    private static void prepareLine(String patternToDraw,StringBuilder sb,int nb){
      for(int i=0;i<nb;i++){
        sb.append(patternToDraw);
      }
        sb.append("\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void multiply(int x, String heart)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        System.out.print(heart);
    System.out.println(); // need for next line
}

// For x = 2; heart = "<3 "
// multiply(x, heart) would output "<3 <3"
```

_

```
// ...

String heart = "  _  _ ";
String heart2 =" ( \\/ )";
String heart3 ="  \\  / ";
String heart4 = "   \\/  ";
int x = 0; // a number you want to print

multiply(x, heart);
multiply(x, heart2);
multiply(x, heart3);
multiply(x, heart4);

// ...
```

Comment: This will not work with multiple lines.

Comment: In his example, he clearly said he would repeat it four times.

Comment: And still, because of the appending nature of standard output, this will not print his expected output.

Comment: Maybe you should use a `String` return type and use your method like this `System.out.println(multiply(x,heart));`

Comment: @RileyCarney OK, this works, a better name for the function variable `heart` is in order I suppose :) also, fix the last from: `"  \/  "` to `"   \/  "` (added space).

Comment: Yeah, I was testing it, you also need to put in escape character before \, such as \\ for it to work. I forgot the System.out.println() at end of multiply, adding that now.